# Django-how the Cancel button in Html template is usually implemented?

Tags: html, button

I am learning web development in Django. There is a page createInfo.html where user enter the informatino and there are two buttons, save and cancel.Here is what I write for cancel button

```
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel()"/>


<script>
    function cancel() {
        c=confirm("Do you really want to cancel?");
        if (c==true)
        {

        }
        else{
        }
</script>
```

How to implement the script so that

- if the user click OK on the pop up for cancel button-->stay on this
  page,but all the data cleared, i.e. a fresh createInfo Page
- if the
  user click Cancel on the pop up--> stay as before(with all the data
  untouched)

Can anyone help provide some code on how to implement the cancel button? Or how this is normally implemented if my design is not correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't follow your question, 
do you want to open a new page on cancel or do you want to clear the content of the current page?

Comment: just clear the content of the page would be okie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a `submit` button, you can use a `reset` button instead, e.g.

```
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

Additionally, if you want a confirmation dialog, you can attach it as before. You need to add a little extra though:

```
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="return cancel()" />

<script>
    function cancel() {
        c=confirm("Do you really want to cancel?");

        // Of course, the following could be shortened to "return c;"
        if (c==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

For most HTML `onXyz()` handlers, you can return a value from the handler that dictates whether the action should take place. By returning false from this, the action (i.e. the reset in this case) is discarded. By returning true, you allow the action to actually happen.

Of course, if you want more control over the reset, or you don't want to use a reset button, you can manually clear all of the controls using Javascript, for example

```
<script>
    function cancel() {
        c=confirm("Do you really want to cancel?");

        if (c==true)
        {
            $('#my_text_box').val("");
            $('#my_other_box').val("");
            $('#another_control').val("Default value");
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much,it works exactly as what I want and thanks for explaining how it works.

Comment: sorry but what does the part of  $('#my_text_box').val("");
            $('#my_other_box').val("");
            $('#another_control').val("Default value"); affect? I've tries this code but cannot see the difference of this with the previous code without this part.

Comment: @Mona It's just using jQuery to manually set the values of text boxes (with IDs of `my_text_box` etc) to whatever value you want. I'd suggest having a read through the jQuery manual to find more information.